# Calculate $\int_0^2 x^2 e^x dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

How do I calculate 
$$\int_0^2 x^2 e^x dx$$

Is there a product rule for integration ?

Comment: Look up "integration by parts". You'll need to do it twice here.

Comment: In a sense, yes there is a product rule for integration. It's the integration by parts formula; which is obtained by integrating both sides of the product rule for derivatives: $$ (fg)'=f'g+g'f\Rightarrow fg=\int f'g+\int g'f.$$Rearranging the above gives the integration by parts formula (which is useful for your integral):$$\int f'g=fg-\int g'f.$$

Comment: @DavidMitra Wow :O ,  now I really understand ! Thank you!

Off-topic, how should I ask my question next time? To make sure it isn't downvoted. I couldn't find this integration by parts trick in my (highschool) book, and on wikipedia it just looked so difficult. But luckily now I understand :)

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems you're in the position where you have to ask a basic (to people who have studied math for a while) question without providing any work. I imagine for this reason, some people deemed it worthy of a downvote (I didn't downvote). Perhaps next time you're in this situation, explain where the problem came from, your background concerning the relevant subject, and why you find the problem intractable. See [this thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question) for other advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer of your question is yes, existis. The conection is the fundamental theorem of calculus and produtc ruler diferentiation. We have that
$$
D_x(u(x)\cdot v(x))=v(x)\cdot D_x u(x)+u(x)\cdot D_x v(x)
$$
implies
$$
v(x)\cdot D_x u(x)= D_x(u(x)\cdot v(x)) -u(x)\cdot D_x v(x)
$$
and 
$$
\int^b_a v(x)\cdot D_x u(x)\, dx= \int^b_a D_x(u(x)\cdot v(x))\,dx -\int^b_a u(x)\cdot D_x v(x)\, dx
$$
By Fundamental Theorem of Calculus
$$
\int^b_a v(x)\cdot D_x u(x)\, dx= u(x)\cdot v(x)\bigg|^b_a -\int^b_a u(x)\cdot D_x v(x)\, dx
$$ 
This is the formula of  integration by parts.
\begin{align}
\int^{2}_{0} x^2 e^x dx=
&
\int^{2}_{0} x^2 (e^x)^{\prime} dx
& 
(e^x)^{\prime}=e^x
\\
=
&
x^2e^x\bigg|^{2}_{0}-\int|^{2}_{0} (x^2)^{\prime}  e^xdx
&
\mbox{formula of  integration by parts}
\\
=
&
x^2e^x\bigg|^{2}_{0}-\int^{2}_{0}2xe^xdx
&
(x^2)^{\prime}=2x
\\
=
&
x^2e^x\bigg|^{2}_{0}-2\int^{2}_{0} x (e^x)^{\prime} dx
&
(e^x)^{\prime}=e^x
\\
=
&
x^2e^x\bigg|^{2}_{0}-2xe^x\bigg|^{2}_{0}+2\int^{2}_{0} e^x dx
&
\mbox{formula of  integration by parts}
\\
=
&
x^2e^x-2xe^x+2e^x\bigg|^{2}_{0}
&
\end{align}

Comment: I've never seen the notation $D_x$. I like this notation, is this the standard notation ?

Comment: And thank you for this long informative post ! I absolutely love it !

Comment: @90intuition This is too a standard notation. See any calculus book. Good look.

Answer (score 3):

We shall use integration by parts:
$$\int f^{\prime}(x)g(x)dx=f(x)g(x)-\int f(x)g^{\prime}(x)dx$$

We have $$\int x^2 e^x dx=\int x^2 (e^x)^{\prime} dx=x^2e^x-\int (x^2)^{\prime}  e^xdx=x^2e^x-\int2xe^xdx=\\x^2e^x-2\int x (e^x)^{\prime} dx=x^2e^x-2xe^x+2\int e^x=x^2e^x-2xe^x+2e^x+c$$

Comment: The final answer is then $x^2e^x-2xe^x+2e^x|_0^2$ ?

Comment: @90intuition Yes

Comment: Thanks for your amazingly quick answer! I understand I think. You're using $f(x)=x^2$ and $g'(x)=e^x$ ?

Comment: @90intuition In the first integration by parts I do. In the second, I use $f(x)=x$ and $g^{\prime}(x)=e^x$

Comment: Why is my question down voted ?

Answer (score 3):

$$f(r) = \int_0^{2} e^{rx} dx = \frac{e^2 - 1}{r}$$
$$f'(r) = \int_0^{2} xe^{rx} dx = -\frac{e^2 - 1}{r^2}$$
$$f''(r) = \int_0^{2} x^2e^{rx} dx = \frac{2e^2 - 2}{r^3}$$
$$f''(1) = \int_0^{2} x^2e^{x} dx = 2e^2 - 2$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Note that $$\int_0^2 x^ne^xdx=\int_0^2 x^nd(e^x)=x^ne^x|_0^2-n\int_0^2 x^{n-1}e^xdx$$
Now continue reducing the power of $x$.

Comment: If you call LHS as $I(n)$, then $I(n) = 2^ne^2 - nI(n - 1)$, therefore $I(2) = 4e^2 - 2(2e^2 - I(0)) = 4e^2 - 4e^2 + 2I(0) = 2e^2 - 2$ where $I(0)$ is explicitly evaluated.